# Is there any reason not to use Powerpoint for Application Drawings?

Tags: patent-drawings

An invention has no circuits or mechanical engineering drawings, there are however maps of how to deploy sensors and maps to for sequential data flow & processing.

Is there any reason not to use Power Point to create drawings?

Any examples of reasons not to use Power Point are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you may use Powerpoint, but there are some decent reasons not to. First and foremost, Powerpoint simply isn't that good for drawing graphics (in my humble opinion), especially if you are doing diagrams like flowcharts. Visio is designed for this sort of thing as is the open source [Dia](http://dia-installer.de). With diagramming software, the lines that link blocks stay linked to their assigned nodes which makes editing and adjusting the position of blocks easy.

If you do use Powerpoint, you need to make sure you are avoiding many of the features it provides (often by default) like color, drop shadows, 3D text, etc. You want a plain black line on white background illustration.

Comment: Oh right, there are *technical* reasons.

Comment: @DonQuiKong I see the little edit you just made to your answer! I'm a bit anal about using the right tool for the job. I once knew a person who used Excel to write their memos because they didn't want to learn Word.

Comment: haha, and you're right of course, time is money, no need to waste it on the wrong tools.

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no legal reason not to use Power Point.

Answer (score 0):

There is no restriction/permission by the patent office for the use of any software.

However, there are some guidelines related to formatting of drawings that need to be follow, for eg. page margin, page size, sheet number etc.

You can use any software to make drawings as long as the guidelines are complied and **drawings are clear to understand**.